# Selenium Webdriver C# Drop downs in a For Loop stale element reference

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

When I'm running through the For Loop I'm only able to iterate once, without the "value" showing as stale. What is occurring, I need to select the value from the first drop down to populate the options for the second.

I've attempted to setup the element references in a way that should not be showing as stale.

```
//Order Type dropdown menu
        String OrderTypeDropDown = "//*[@id='OrderTypeId']";
        IWebElement drpOrderType = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(OrderTypeDropDown));            

        //Select the order type dropdown
        SelectElement select = new SelectElement(drpOrderType);

        //Make a list of all order type dropdown options 
        IList<IWebElement> elements = select.Options;        

        //Itterate through all the options in the order type dropdown
        foreach (IWebElement value in elements)
        {
            //Click the option
            value.Click();

            //Print out the option
            Console.WriteLine(value.Text);

            //Sleep
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            //Change Type dropdown menu stale element reference setup
            String RequestChangeDropDown = "//*[@id='RequestedChange']";

            IWebElement drpChangeType = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(RequestChangeDropDown));

            //Select the Requested Change dropdown
            SelectElement drpSelect = new SelectElement(drpChangeType);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(RequestChangeDropDown)).Click();

            //Make a list of all Requested Change types
            IList<IWebElement> change = drpSelect.Options;

            foreach (IWebElement option in change)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(option.Text);                   
            }

        }
```

Error Message: 
    OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException : stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
      (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)
  Stack Trace: 
    RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
    RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
    RemoteWebElement.Click()
    TSR_Forms.Mobile_Device_Request_Orders() line 907

Comment: Initial glance at your code everything is "FindElement" and if you want a list, you will need "FindElements" so all items that match the xpath are iterated through.

Answer (score 0):

You must wait until element be clickable :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath(RequestChangeDropDown)));
```

therefor, you can click it.
The problem is you are trying to click an element which is not clickable in DOM yet!